# convert table value to JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a table. 
**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped" id="table-visual-features">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visual Feature</th>
                <th>Type [currently not used]</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>A11</td><td>Numeric [1..30]</td><td>Values to be mapped to the S1-axis</td><td><button class="action-change">edit</button> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger action-remove-visual-feature">remove</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td>A21</td><td>Numeric [1..10 ]</td><td>Values to be mapped to the S2-axis</td><td><button class="action-change">edit</button> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger action-remove-visual-feature">remove</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td>A31</td><td>Numeric [1..20 ]</td><td>Values to be mapped to the S3-axis</td><td><button class="action-change">edit</button> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger action-remove-visual-feature">remove</button></td></tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to convert my value from table  to this form

```
var features = {
    features: {
        "A11": {"type_feature": "Numeric [1..30]", "description_feature": "Values to be mapped to the S1-axis"},
        "A21": {"type_feature": "Numeric [1..10]", "description_feature": "Values to be mapped to the S2-axis"},
        "A31": {"type_feature": "Numeric [1..20]", "description_feature": "Values to be mapped to the S3-axis"}
    }
};
```

I take the value of the first cell in the row, it is "A11".
The value of the second cell in the row is "Numeric [1..30]".
The value of the third cell in the row is "Values to be mapped to the S1-axis".
We first entry

```
features: {
            "A11": {"type_feature": "Numeric [1..30]", "description_feature": "Values to be mapped to the S1-axis"}}
```

this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7q3KP/

Please help me to convert value. Thank you in advance

Comment: not clear what are you trying to say?

Comment: FTI: That's not a JSON value.  It's a JavaScript object.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that resembles JavaScript syntax.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Comment: @Subhash: He wants to "convert" the HTML table to a JavaScript object.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var features = {features:{}};
$('tr:not(:first)').each(function () {
    var name = $(this).find('td:first').text(); 
    features["features"][name] = {
        "type_feature": $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),
        "description_feature": $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text()
    } 
});
console.log(features);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/7q3KP/2/)

Comment: yahooooooooooooooooooooo! thank you for your solution. It is very helpful for me!!!

Comment: Ah that was for OPs first edit, the tds were called S1A @richarddalton

Answer (score 2):

This code will loop over the rows and extract the data into your features object:

```
var features = { features: {}};

$('#table-visual-features tbody tr').each(function() {
     var cells = $(this).find('td');
     features.features[cells.eq(0).text()] = { 
        "type_feature": cells.eq(1).text(),
        "description_feature": cells.eq(2).text()
     };
});

console.log(features);
```

JSFiddle Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Bdv4L/

Comment: As grateful as I am for the accepted answer it should probably go to Anton as he posted basically exactly the same answer as me two minutes before I did.